Cisco AnyConnect VPN fails with illegal or unsupported version
I'm attempting to connect to a Cisco AnyConnect VPN from my Fedora 40 client. I tried both the GUI (lots of howtos out there) and the terminal to establish this connection through OpenConnect and fails with:
SSL connection failure: A packet with illegal or unsupported version was received.
Failed to open HTTPS connection to vpn.vpn.vpn

This is actual connection attempt:
$ openconnect vpn.vpn.vpn 
POST https://vpn.vpn.vpn/
Connected to 0.0.0.0:443
SSL negotiation with vpn.vpn.vpn
SSL connection failure: A packet with illegal or unsupported version was received.
Failed to open HTTPS connection to vpn.vpn.vpn
Failed to complete authentication


It seems that some old and deprecated ciphers might be used on the VPN server side. Therefore, the solution that worked for me was to allow legacy:
sudo update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY

Following this, I was establish the connection:
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.vpn.vpn with ciphersuite (TLS1.0)-(DHE-CUSTOM1024)-(AES-256-CBC)-(SHA1)

